# How to filter all returned values from methods in class

Tags: php, oop

I inherited this PHP project.  I've got one class which contains maybe 20 different methods, most of which return values.  I'd like to filter every value returned by methods in this class.  Is there a simple and elegant way to do this, or must I wrap every value in a filter method before it is returned?

The class looks like this:

```
class db_ops
{

    // ...

    public function get_var($query) {
        // ...
        return $values;
    }

    public function get_name($query) {
        // ...
        return $name;
    }

    // ...

}
```

Comment: Show us your code. Explain in more detail what it's doing and what you'd like it to do. Possible give an example. Like this, we have no idea what you're talking about. There's only a couple of hundred ways to "filter" something..

Comment: Anyway. Taking it to the basic: There are 2 places where you can "filter" something. Inside the method or wherever the value is returned in your code. If your "filter" can be applied to all the different methods, then it's best to do the latter. Otherwise you have to do it inside the method. If for example you want to filter integers, but some methods return a string, it would cause problems if that string goes through the same filter.

Comment: Thanks.  So there's no way I can write some extra code which basically says "filter all values returned by any method in class X"?

Comment: It depends on what kind of filter you want? It's impossible to give you a detailed answer without detailed information. That's why I told you to explain what the code does: _What kind of values are returned?_ And what do you want to achiev? _The end result after your filter_

Comment: They all return strings or arrays of strings.  I would be scanning for specific substrings in those strings and then replacing them if necessary.

Comment: So what does this tell you? `They ALL return strings or arrays of strings`. So it's safe to assume that 1 single filter can be applied to all your methods. You also want to do 1 specific task no matter which method returned a value. The only difference is that it might be a string or an array. So all you have to do is write a function or method for the filter and use an if statement that does its work depending on if the returned value is an array or a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used a sort of wrapper class to do something like this before. Here's a generic example, just to show how it works. If you like this idea you should be able implement your own along these lines.

```
class FilteredExample
{
    private $example;

    function __construct($example)
    {
        $this->example = $example;
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        if (method_exists($this->example, $name)) {

            $result = call_user_func_array([$this->example, $name], $arguments);

            if (is_string($result)) {
                return "$result filtered";
            } elseif (is_array($result)) {
                return array_map(function($item){ return "$item filtered"; }, $result);
            } else {
                return $result;
            }

        } else {
            throw new BadMethodCallException("Method '$name' not found", 1);
        }
    }
}
```

You inject the object whose methods you want to filter in the constructor, and then use the [`__call()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) magic method so that you can call all of the original object's methods. With [`method_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php), you can validate any called method and throw an exception if it doesn't exist, just like you'd get if you called it on the original object. If it *does* exist, then you can call it with [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php), filter the result, and return it.

I added a little section to show that you can handle different result types, or just return the unmodified result if it's not a certain type. You obviously wouldn't need to do this if all your original object's methods return the same type.

Here is an example of how you could use it based on the example class from your question:

```
$dbOps = new db_ops;
$filteredDbOps = new FilteredExample($dbOps);
$result = $filteredDbOps->get_var('something');
```